# docker-machine create with digitalocean driver and Ubuntu 16.04 x64 fails

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, ubuntu-16.04

I am attempting to create a docker machine on Digital Ocean, but with the 16.04 LTS instead of the default 15.10.  The do-access-token file contains my token.

Here's the script (create-do):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Creates a digital-ocean server with Ubuntu 16.04 instead of the default
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
echo "Creating: " $1
docker-machine                                          \
  create                                                \
  --driver digitalocean                                 \
  --digitalocean-access-token=`cat do-access-token`   \
  --digitalocean-image=ubuntu-16-04-x64             \
  --digitalocean-ipv6=true                          \
  $1
else
  echo "Must have server name!"
fi
```

When I run the script like this:

```
$ ./create-do ps-server
```

It successfully allocates the machine at Digital Ocean, then craps out with this:

```
Creating:  ps-server
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(ps-server) Creating SSH key...
(ps-server) Creating Digital Ocean droplet...
(ps-server) Waiting for IP address to be assigned to the Droplet...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with ubuntu(systemd)...
Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: Something went wrong 
running an SSH command!
command : sudo apt-get update
err     : exit status 100
output  : Reading package lists...
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

The machine is running, but I can't get to it since the SSH key was apparently not set before things started going wrong.

Anyone seen this before and/or have a work-around?

Answer (score 1):

Update: May 21, 2016
Broken again with same error this morning.  Tried 4 times, failed same way each time.

Update: May 20, 2016

This was, according do Digital Ocean's support, due to an issue with their Ubuntu 16.04 image which has now been corrected and I have confirmed that this now works.

Related GitHub issue (not yet closed):

https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3358

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
docker-machine provision your-node
```

I've taken this solution from here: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3358

I hope this helps!